# node.js fix error: SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: node.js, docker, imap

I am trying to connect to an IMAP server, but using different packages I always get this error:

```
Error: 139844877236160:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
```

I have the feeling that this is due to some nodejs configuration. I am running nodejs with the latest version in docker from https://hub.docker.com/_/node .

How can I change the ssl3 version number?

```
const Imap = require("imap");
onst imap = new Imap({
  user: "xx",
  password: "xx",
  host: "imap.ionos.com",
  port: 993,
  tls: true,
  authTimeout: 3000,
});

imap.once("error", function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});

imap.once("end", function () {
  console.log("Connection ended");
});

imap.connect();
```

Comment: You are probably using the wrong port or configuration.  You usually get this when you try to connect to a plain text port with a TLS socket.  Please show the code you and configuration you are using to try to connect to the server; alternatively, you're connecting to a sever using an extremely old version of SSL which is not secure or supported by modern libraries.

Comment: i edited the question with the code, this is the normal imap port :(

Comment: I poked at it with openssl s_client and socat, and the server seems to support modern TLS (versions 1.0 - 1.2), so something else seems to be wrong with your local configuration.  Transparent firewall?  Bad port mapping?  Not sure.